# Celery Webhook Script in PhantomJS

Tags: celery, phantomjs, webhooks

I am trying to use celery to create a task management system, where the tasks are written in phantomjs. Basically the task is to crawl a URL and return a JSON object (that I'll want to use once the task is complete). There will be a list of URLs which will each have it's own crawl task.

I looked at this http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/remote-tasks.html#calling-webhook-tasks to implement tasks in another language. However celery  does not provide very good documentation at all on how the external webhook script should be written, what dependencies are required, and how it is run.

Should the task simply be stored on a server, which I will call with the HTTPCallback? How is it run in the PhantomJS framework. How are results from here stored or returned and how do I keep track of it? I have read a lot of docs and I still cannot find the exact interface or API for the other side of the webhook API.

I realize my question may not be too clear, so let me know, otherwise some good examples of this HTTPCallback API workflow would be helpful for a basic understanding, and how the webhook script in a different language is structured.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!